# Number Limited to 9 digits in Oracle Merge Query?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to use a merge query with parameters in an oracle db (11g). I came across a problem that baffles me. When I run a query using a number greater than 9 digits for the SESSION_ID, no match occurs and a new row is created with the SESSION_ID set to 0.

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE CLASSES ("SESSION_ID" NUMBER(19,0), "CLASS_NAME" NCHAR(255))
```

This query works fine with any number of digits, up to 19, for the SESSION_ID:

```
MERGE INTO CLASSES db
USING (select 22507410978 AS SESSION_ID from dual) geo
ON (geo.SESSION_ID = db.SESSION_ID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET db.CLASS_NAME = 'My Class Name'
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (db.SESSION_ID, db.CLASS_NAME) VALUES (22507410978, 'My Class Name');
```

This query works fine for any number of digits, up to 9. After 9 digits, SESSION_ID is set to 0. (I'm testing this using SQL Developer and inputing the values for SESSION_ID and CLASS_NAME via the ENTER BIND dialog.

```
MERGE INTO CLASSES db
USING (select :session_id AS SESSION_ID from dual) geo
ON (geo.SESSION_ID = db.SESSION_ID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET db.CLASS_NAME = :class_name
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (db.SESSION_ID, db.CLASS_NAME) VALUES (:session_id, :class_name);
```

So, this value will work for SESSION_ID (2250741091) but this won't (22507410911).

Any ideas?

Comment: I tried your code, and I don't get that behavior.

Comment: *"this value will work for SESSION_ID (2250741091)"*: That's 10 digits. I thought you said you could only go up to 9 digits.

Comment: You are correct it is 10 digits, not 9. Anything more than 10 digits inserts a 0. The problem is the same, though.

Comment: What if you do not set the values through SQL Developer bind variables?

Answer (score 1):

The problem has nothing to do with the fact that you are trying to perform a `merge` statement.  But it does appear to be a limitation (bug?) in how Oracle SQL Developer binds number variables when using the `Enter Binds` dialog box.

It would appear that when you type in a value for a bind variable, it tries to be smart about determining the data type of the value you enter.  If it detects a number, it tries to bind it as a 4-byte signed integer value.  However, if your number is too large for a 4-byte signed integer value (smaller than `-1,147,483,648`, or greater than `1,147,483,647`), the binding fails and sets a default value of `0`.  (I don't know that what I describe in this paragraph is all factual, but testing suggests that something along these lines must be going on)

To avoid what could be considered "buggy" behavior in SQL Developer, consider bypassing the `Enter Binds` dialog box entirely by defining and setting your binding variable values ahead of time as part of your script.

For instance, if you run the following in SQL Developer, it won't prompt you to enter the bind values, and you will find that the inserted values are correct:

```
var session_id number
var class_name nchar(255)
begin
  :session_id := 22507410978;
  :class_name := 'My Class Name';

  MERGE INTO CLASSES db
  USING (select :session_id AS SESSION_ID from dual) geo
  ON (geo.SESSION_ID = db.SESSION_ID)
  WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET db.CLASS_NAME = :class_name
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (db.SESSION_ID, db.CLASS_NAME) VALUES (:session_id, :class_name);
end;
/
```

**EDIT**

David Aldridge suggested the interesting idea of entering the bind value as a textual value, and then have the SQL convert it back to a number, by changing the SQL like this:

```
to_number(:session_id)
```

Unfortunately, the `Enter Binds` dialog box doesn't allow you to specify the data type when you are entering a value.  So even if your SQL statement expects a string value, when you type in `22507410978` in the prompt, it will detect that the entered value looks like a number and will attempt to convert the value (incorrectly) to a 4-byte signed integer, resulting in a value of `0` all the same.

Taking this a step further, this actually means that your `:class_name` bind variable, which binds to an `nchar` column, could also break if you typed in a very large number.  If you try your original test, and type in `22507410978` when prompted for the `:class_name` value, you'll see that the character `0` is inserted in the `class_name` column.

Based on my observations, I would stay as far away as possible from the `Enter Binds` dialog box if I were you.

Comment: Hmmm, interesting. I shall delete my suggestion. Hopefully this will be fixed in SQLDeveloper.